# Laravel не видит view

Tags: php, laravel

Создаю я, значит, контроллер, вьюшку к нему и маршрут соответственно.
Переходя по этому маршруту ларка говорит мне, что вьюшка не найдена, хотя имя файла я указала правильно.

Код контроллера

```php
class ImageGalleryController extends Controller
{
    public function select($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);

        return view('products.images.select', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

Маршрут

```php
Route::get('/products/{id}/selectimages', 'ImageGalleryController@select')
```

Почему лара не видит view?

Comment: покажите структуру файлов view, откуда мы можем знать где у вас файлы лежат

Comment: https://prnt.sc/r63xl6 — пожалуйста, не бейте за скриншот :D

Comment: что выдает `ls -la resources/views/products/images/select.blade.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для метода view папка resources/views является точкой отсчёта, т.е. для корректной работы ваш файл blade должен был бы лежать в views/products/images/select.blade.php (на скрине не видно корня). В коде приведённом вами нет ошибок, есть опечатка = не хватает ";" в конце строчки:

```
Route::get('/products/{id}/selectimages', 'ImageGalleryController@select')
```

Я надеюсь смог помочь Вам!)

Comment: Хоть Вы мне и не помогли, но спасибо. Я, идиотка, ошибку свою нашла. Не скажу, в чём она заключался, ибо очень стыдно :D